# SugarCRM credentials not working

Tags: php, api, rest, laravel-4, sugarcrm

I'm a PHP Developer, I'm using this library for my Laravel 4.2
https://github.com/asakusuma/SugarCRM-REST-API-Wrapper-Class

I wanted to retrieve data from a user. I already have an account in sugarCRM
I can log in successfully here: https://web.sugarcrm.com/user

A PHP code sample from the library I'm using:

```
$sugar = new \Asakusuma\SugarWrapper\Rest;

$sugar->setUrl('https://sugarcrm/service/v2/rest.php');
$sugar->setUsername('user');
$sugar->setPassword('password');

$sugar->connect();

$results = $sugar->get("Accounts",array('id','name'));

print_r($results);
```

I used my username and password the way i used to log in in the sugarCRM.

Answer (score 0):

1. `https://web.sugarcrm.com/user` is SugarCRM's website for support, news, software downloads, managing subscriptions, etc. It is not an actual SugarCRM instance.
2. When you set your URL you set it to `https://sugarcrm/service/v2/rest.php` which is (a) not a valid URL and (b) different than the URL you were aiming for

I've used Asa API library several times in the past and it really is excellent. Gets you moving around a not-quiet-RESTful API very quickly. So good choice on the tool. You just need to point it at an actual SugarCRM system.

Go to the [main SugarCRM website](http://www.sugarcrm.com/) and click the green "Free Trial" button in the top right corner to register for a "demo" instance of Sugar. The company will email you a URL where you can actually log in to a system and review it. This will likely be an instance of SugarCRM Professional 7.5 and be hosted on a URL that begins with `https://demo.sugarcrm.com/something`.

This "demo" will expire in some number of days. If you'd like a limit-less experience, pay for it or review SugarCRM Community Edition, the open source version of the same software. In fact, since you're new to the system, it's probably worth installing CE and comparing it to the paid-for Professional edition just for the familiarity. Both systems allow use of the "REST v4.1" API, although the newer paid systems have a new REST API v10 to offer as well.

The latest Community Edition is available on as a [SourceForge Project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sugarcrm/files/).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your url which is invalid.

**$sugar->setUrl('https://sugarcrm/service/v2/rest.php');**

It should be taking value of the url where your CRM resides and which means it should look like the below

**$sugar->setUrl('http://127.0.0.1/my_crm/service/v4_1/rest.php');**

Comment: that was just an example , its the url to where your crm reside which can take any value